# Working with names and values of objects in a list in R using loops

Tags: r, list

how do you retrieve the names of the objects of a list in a loop. I want to do something like this:

```
lst = list(a = c(1,2), b = 1)

for(x in lst){
#print the name of the object x in the list
# print the multiplication of the values
}
```

Desired results:

```
"a"
2 4
"b"
2
```

In Python one can use dictionary and with the below code get the desired results:

```
lst = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":1} 

for key , value in lst.items():
   print(key)
   print(value * 2)
```

but since in R we have no dictionary data structure, I am trying to achieve this using lists but I don't know how to return the objects names. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: edited the question. I want to iterate both on the objects and on the labels. Your solution just allows for iterations over names but not the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `names` directly

```
names(lst)
[1] "a" "b"
```

---

Or if we want to `print` in a loop, loop over the sequence or `names` of the `list`, `print` the name, as well as the value got by extracting the list element based on the name multiplied

```
for(nm in  names(lst)) {
     print(nm)
     print(lst[[nm]] * 2)
  }
[1] "a"
[1] 2 4
[1] "b"
[1] 2
```

---

Or another option is `iwalk`

```
library(purrr)
iwalk(lst, ~ {print(.y); print(.x * 2)})
[1] "a"
[1] 2 4
[1] "b"
[1] 2
```